# Can't bind parameters to WHERE clause PDO

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo, prepared-statement

I use a lot of sql statements using PostgreSQL and PHP and many of them have variables in the 'WHERE' clause. I can get prepared statements to execute just fine for INSERT and UPDATE but I can't make it work for SELECT statements with variables in the WHERE clause. I have scoured google for an answer with no success. Please take a look at the example below. This is to select a recent reconciled bank balance from a table called bankrec. What am I missing?

```
$rec = $dbh->prepare('SELECT clearedbal FROM bankrec WHERE bankno = :bankno ');
$result = $rec->execute(['bankno'=>$bankno])->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

When I run this I get:

```
"Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean"
```

However, I know the query is correct because simply running a query without a prepared statement gets me the result I want, but it is vulnerable to sql injection:

```
$rec = $dbh->query("SELECT clearedbal FROM bankrec WHERE bankno = '$bankno' ")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Dont chain it, it should be `$rec->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` but execute returns `bool`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Well that was a simple fix! That works! Why can I chain it like that for INSERT and UPDATE but not SELECT? Thank you very much!

Comment: @AppreciateCo `execute()` returns a Boolean, while `query()` returns a `PDOStatement`, which allows you to do method chaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see on [this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) link you the PDO's `execute` method returns boolean by definition.

I would recommend this approach:

```php
$rec = $dbh->prepare('SELECT clearedbal FROM bankrec WHERE bankno = :bankno ');
if($rec->execute(['bankno'=>$bankno])){
  $result=$rec->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  //do another stuff there
} else {
  //Query failed handle error
}
```

As you can see you can use the `execute` in order to determine if query sucessfully executed or not. Also if you need to fetch more than one line of result you should use the `fetchAll` method: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: Thanks Dimitrios. You said basically the same thing as Lawrence. I can't mark a comment as an answer, so I marked yours. Thanks to both of you.